# jQuery Validate: Add events to submit button click in ASP.NET MVC 5 Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. The application is already using the jQuery Validate plug-in that is provided with a MVC application. Currently, when the "submit" button is clicked, jQuery Validate is triggered, the form is validated and submitted if valid.

I need to add a couple more events to the submit button click and I need to ensure that the new events do not override the jQuery Validate plugin. Originally I tried this code without jQuery Validate:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
  // JavaScript event
 // another JavaScript event
});
```

But when I tested this code, it completely overrode the jQuery Validate plug-in and all of my front-end validation disappeared. I'm wondering if I somehow included jQuery Validate into this code, it would allow the plugin and new submit button events to coexist.

I'm imagining the code will look something like this:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
   //Initialize jQuery Validate plug-in
  // JavaScript event that happens if form is valid
 // another JavaScript event that happens if form is valid
});
```

How do I call jQuery Validate that is already set up by ASP.NET's MVC framework? I do not need to change the plug-in at all (unless my plan of action is wrong); I just need to add events to the submit button click.

Comment: So currently the jQuery validate code *works*, correct?  And you're just trying to add a click event handler to a button?  Well, what you're showing is indeed a click event handler for a button.  Is this *not working* in some way?  It's not really clear to me where you're stuck.

Comment: Hi David, when I tried to create this jQuery code without initializing the jQuery Validate plug-in, the application stopped validating. I think the new code overrode the plug-in. I'm wondering if I call the plug-in within the code above, it will work. I'm, however, not sure what that code would look like.

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize the jQuery validate plugin"?  Isn't that "initialized" elsewhere in the page's code?  Why would it need to be initialized again?  Simply adding a click handler doesn't override anything.  But if you have other code which is causing a problem in some way, we can't know that based on the information provided.

Comment: It seems like there must be another piece of code within the jQuery Validate that is already performing an action on the submit button click. I'm guessing it's all of the front-end validation. When I tried to do a separate, $('#submitButton').click(function(){
  // JavaScript event
 // another JavaScript event
});            it completely overrode the jQuery Validate plugin and all of my front-end validation disappeared.

Comment: You **cannot** initialize this plugin more than once.  It will ignore any subsequent attempts after this first initialization.

Comment: You also should not be initializing this plugin within the `click` event of the `submit` button.  After all, during `submit`, you're already past when you'd need validation.

Answer (score 0):

Great.. I think You are trying to **SUBMIT** a form which was created either using

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm.. or @using (Html.BeginForm(..
```

both of these contains a function **OnBegin** which can call any function that will fire before the form Submit

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveInformation_Basic", "..//ARCSL1", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "done._afterEntry", OnBegin = "return Prevalidateform();" }, new { @id = "entryForm" }))


function Prevalidateform() {
   // do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it in button event

```
    $('#submitButton').click(function(){
      var $form = $('form');
      if($form.valid()){
      // JavaScript event that happens if form is valid
      }
      else{    // another JavaScript event that happens if form is valid
      }
    });
```